# JQuery Datepicker default date not working

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datepicker

I am new to knockout.JS,  I find out it does not work when I want to set default date for my datepicker in dateoptions.

```
<td><input type="text" class ="mainautoinput" data-bind="jqDatePicker: BuildDate, 
                        datepickerOptions: { changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        buttonImageOnly: true,
                        buttonImage: '../../../../Images/calendar.jpg',
                        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                            var month = $('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected').val();
                            var year = $('#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected').val();
                            BuildDate(new Date(year, month, 1));
                        }
                        } " /></td>
```

The default date is always 03/02/2025 I really do not understand why. It seems that the default date option is not working

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var today = new Date()

'defaultDate': {
    year: today.getFullYear(),
    month: today.getMonth() + 1,
    day: today.getDate()
 }
```